# Calling powershell script from ASP.NET does not work. Calling script from cmd works fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, sharepoint

Good day,
Since SharePoint can't be used via .NET Core anymore (except from using graph), I wrote a ps1 that does the following :

- Initialize
- Connect
- Check the folder
- Uploads the file(s)

When I run the ps1 with PowerShell ISE, it works just fine. I get the message that the files are uploaded in the correct folders, and it this is correct. Folder is created, files are uploaded.

So now I want to call this script from ASP MVC using PowerShell.SDK.
The return is 400 Bad Request. Strange, but ok.

What I did was remove the inbound arguments and have them hardcoded. Even this fails with the same error ... How can it be that a ps1 runs perfectly on its own, and fails when called from .NET ??

if the PowerShell code is crappy, sorry, just learned it yesterday :)

**PowerShell**

```
#Param(
#    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$url,
#    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$user,
#    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$password,
#    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$basefolder,
#    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$uploadfolder,
#    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$filepath1,
#    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$filepath2
#)

$url = "https://blablabla.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite"
$user = "support@blablabla.be"
$password = "password"
$basefolder = "/sites/mySite/Gedeelde Documenten/"
$uploadfolder = "TestGlenn/demo"
$filepath1 = "C:\\Klant_20230911205406734.json"
$filepath2 = "C:\\Klant_latest.json"

function Initialize {

    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

    $global:ErrorOccured = $false
    $global:FolderExists = $false
    $global:Return = ""
    $global:Credentials = $null
    $global:Context = $null
    $global:Web = $null
}

function Connect {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$url_conn,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$user_conn,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$password_conn            
    )

    $securePassword= $password_conn | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
    $global:Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($user_conn,$securePassword)
    $global:Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url_conn)
    $global:Context.Credentials = $global:Credentials
    $global:Web = $global:Context.Web
    $global:Context.Load($global:Web)
}

function Check-Folder {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$basefolder_chf,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$checkfolder_chf
    )
 
    Try {
        Try {
            $Folder_chf = $global:Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($basefolder_chf + $checkfolder_chf)
            $global:Context.Load($Folder_chf)
            $global:Context.ExecuteQuery()
            $global:FolderExists = $true
        }
        Catch {
            $global:FolderExists = $false
        }
    }
    Catch {
        $global:Return = "E-SharePoint-Fout bij het controleren van folder $basefolder_chf$checkfolder_chf\r\n\r\n" + $_.Exception.Message
        $global:ErrorOccured = $true    
    }
}

function Create-Folder {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param(               
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$basefolder_cf,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$uploadfolder_cf
    )
 
    Try {
        $Folder_cf = $global:Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($basefolder_cf)
        $global:Context.Load($Folder_cf)
        $global:Context.ExecuteQuery()

        $Folders_cf = $Folder_cf.Folders
        $global:Context.Load($Folders_cf)
        $global:Context.ExecuteQuery()
        $global:Context.Load($Folder_cf)
        $Folder_cf.AddSubFolder($uploadfolder_cf)
        $global:Context.ExecuteQuery()      
    }
    Catch {
        $global:Return = "E-SharePoint-Fout bij het creëren van folder $basefolder_cf$uploadfolder_cf\r\n\r\n" + $_.Exception.Message
        $global:ErrorOccured = $true
    }
 }

function Upload-File {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param(               
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$basefolder_uf,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$uploadfolder_uf,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$filepath1_uf,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$filepath2_uf
    )

    $global:File1Success = $false
    $global:File1Error = ""
    $global:File2Success = $false
    $global:File2Error = ""

     Try {
        $TargetFolder_uf = $global:Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($basefolder_uf + $uploadfolder_uf)
        $global:Context.Load($TargetFolder_uf)
        $global:Context.ExecuteQuery()
        
        if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filepath1_uf))) {
            Try {
                $FileStream_uf = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $filepath1_uf)).OpenRead()
                $SourceFileName_uf = Split-path $filepath1_uf -leaf
                $TargetFileURL_uf = $basefolder_uf + $uploadfolder_uf + "/" + $SourceFileName_uf
   
                $FileCreationInfo_uf = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
                $FileCreationInfo_uf.Overwrite = $true
                $FileCreationInfo_uf.ContentStream = $FileStream_uf
                $FileCreationInfo_uf.URL = $TargetFileURL_uf
                $FileUploaded_uf = $TargetFolder_uf.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo_uf)
                $global:Context.ExecuteQuery()
 
                $FileStream_uf.Close()
                $global:File1Success = $true
            }
            Catch {
                $global:File1Error = $_.Exception.Message
                $global:ErrorOccured = $true
            }
        }

        if ((-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filepath2_uf))) -and $global:ErrorOccured -eq $false) {
            Try {
                $FileStream_uf = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $filepath2_uf)).OpenRead()
                $SourceFileName_uf = Split-path $filepath2_uf -leaf
                $TargetFileURL_uf = $basefolder_uf + $uploadfolder_uf + "/" + $SourceFileName_uf
   
                $FileCreationInfo_uf = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
                $FileCreationInfo_uf.Overwrite = $true
                $FileCreationInfo_uf.ContentStream = $FileStream_uf
                $FileCreationInfo_uf.URL = $TargetFileURL_uf
                $FileUploaded_uf = $TargetFolder_uf.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo_uf)
                $global:Context.ExecuteQuery()
 
                $FileStream_uf.Close()
                $global:File2Success = $true
            }
            Catch {
                $global:File2Error = $_.Exception.Message
                $global:ErrorOccured = $true
            }
        }
    }
    Catch {
        $global:Return = "E-SharePoint-Fout bij het opladen van bestanden.\r\n\r\n" + $_.Exception.Message
        $global:ErrorOccured = $true
    }
}

#Start Program
Initialize
Connect -url_conn $url -user_conn $user -password_conn $password
Check-Folder -basefolder_chf $basefolder -checkfolder_chf $uploadfolder
if ($global:ErrorOccured -eq $false) {
    if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filepath1))) {$filename1 = Split-path $filepath1 -leaf}
    if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filepath2))) {$filename2 = Split-path $filepath2 -leaf}
    
    if ($global:FolderExists -eq $false) {
        Create-Folder -basefolder_cf $basefolder -uploadfolder_cf $uploadfolder
    }

    if (($global:ErrorOccured -eq $false) -and ((-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filepath1))) -or (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filepath2)))))
    {
        Upload-File -basefolder_uf $basefolder -uploadfolder_uf $uploadfolder -filepath1_uf $filepath1 -filepath2_uf $filepath2
    }

    if ((-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filepath1))) -and (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filepath2)))) {
        if (($global:File1Success -eq $true) -and ($global:File2Success -eq $true)) {$global:Return = "I-SharePoint-$filename1 en $filename2 op SharePoint geplaatst."}
        if (($global:File1Success -eq $true) -and ($global:File2Success -eq $false)) {$global:Return = "E-SharePoint-$filename1 op SharePoint geplaatst.\r\n\r\n$filename2 gaf volgende error: $global:File2Error."}
        if (($global:File1Success -eq $false) -and ($global:File2Success -eq $true)) {$global:Return = "E-SharePoint-$filename2 op SharePoint geplaatst.\r\n\r\n$filename1 gaf volgende error: $global:File1Error."}
        if (($global:File1Success -eq $false) -and ($global:File2Success -eq $false)) {$global:Return = "E-SharePoint-$filename1 en $filename2 NIET op SharePoint geplaatst.\r\n\r\n$filename1 gaf volgende error: $global:File1Error.\r\n\r\n$filename2 gaf volgende error: $global:File2Error."}
    }

    if ((-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filepath1))) -and (([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filepath2)))) {
        if ($global:File1Success -eq $true) {$global:Return = "I-SharePoint-$filename1 op SharePoint geplaatst."}
        if ($global:File1Success -eq $false) {$global:Return = "E-SharePoint-$filename1 NIET op SharePoint geplaatst, $global:File1Error."}
    }

    if ((([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filepath1))) -and (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($filepath2)))) {
        if ($global:File2Success -eq $true) {$global:Return = "I-SharePoint-$filename2 op SharePoint geplaatst."}
        if ($global:File2Success -eq $false) {$global:Return = "E-SharePoint-$filename2 NIET op SharePoint geplaatst, $global:File2Error."}
    }
}

return $global:Return
```

**ASP.NET**

```
string script = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Glenn\source\repos\blabla\blabla\wwwroot\ps\SharePoint.ps1");

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
powershell.Runspace = runspace;
powershell.AddScript(script);
//powershell.AddParameter("url", "https://blablabla.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite");
//powershell.AddParameter("user", "support@blablabla.be");
//powershell.AddParameter("password", "password");
//powershell.AddParameter("basefolder", "/sites/mySite/Gedeelde Documenten/");
//powershell.AddParameter("uploadfolder", "TestGlenn/demo");
//powershell.AddParameter("filepath1", "C:\\Klant_20230911205406734.json");
//powershell.AddParameter("filepath2", "C:\\Klant_latest.json");
var powershellReturn = powershell.Invoke();
spReturn = powershellReturn.First().ToString();
runspace.Close();
```

As you can see, I just do "powershell.Invoke();", no arguments because for testing, I fill these hardcoded in the script, and still it fails.

Can someone help me please?
Thanks!!

I tried calling it from ASP.NET, initializing works, connecting works, but checking the presence of the folder fails when calling from .NET

**EDIT 1**
after the comments from @Panagiotis Kanavos I have this :

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Web;

namespace CSOM
{
    public class AuthenticationManager : IDisposable
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        private const string tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token";

        private const string defaultAADAppId = "MYTOKEN";

        // Token cache handling
        private static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlimTokens = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
        private AutoResetEvent tokenResetEvent = null;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> tokenCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
        private bool disposedValue;

        internal class TokenWaitInfo
        {
            public RegisteredWaitHandle Handle = null;
        }

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            Uri site = new Uri("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteA");
            string user = "joe.doe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
            SecureString password = GetSecureString($"Password for {user}");

            // Note: The PnP Sites Core AuthenticationManager class also supports this
            using (var authenticationManager = new AuthenticationManager())
            using (var context = authenticationManager.GetContext(site, user, password))
            {
                context.Load(context.Web, p => p.Title);
                await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Title: {context.Web.Title}");
            }
        }

        public ClientContext GetContext(Uri web, string userPrincipalName, SecureString userPassword)
        {
            var context = new ClientContext(web);

            context.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, e) =>
            {
                string accessToken = EnsureAccessTokenAsync(new Uri($"{web.Scheme}://{web.DnsSafeHost}"), userPrincipalName, new System.Net.NetworkCredential(string.Empty, userPassword).Password).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
            };

            return context;
        }
```

Following questions I have now :

1. GetSecureString does not exist in the current context ?
2. public static async Task Main(string[] args), where should I call this if I have a public string "UploadToSharePoint" ?

Comment: `SharePoint can't be used via .NET Core` that's simply wrong. You may be using a discontinued SDK (the [SharePointOnlineCredentials docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj164693(v=office.15)) were last updated in 2018) or obsolete authentication mechanism (which you acknowledge when you say Graph works). The PowerShell script isn't using SharePoint Powershell commands, it's using the SDK classes directly. And since those *don't* work in .NET Core, they can't be called from ASP.NET Core either

Comment: Why don't you use the *supported* SDKs? Almost all cloud services (AWS, Google, Azure) have discontinued username/password logins. All now use OAuth and OpenID Connect, with different scenarios for service and interactive logins. Instead of storing a password, you create an application token

Comment: Powershell runs on top of .NET. You can only host PowerShell Core in a .NET Core application. That means you can't use any .NET Framework classes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what SDK should I be using then ? I don't like using Graph as I have no time to study for 2 weeks how it works :)

Comment: Did you [try the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard#using-modern-authentication-with-csom-for-net-standard)? `I don't like` neither did I ever like SharePoint, and I was an SP MVP for 2 years.

Comment: ok, I'll give it a try @PanagiotisKanavos . Do I need to add ClientContext somewhere special, like in program.cs, or can I have it in a seperate folder to keep it simple ? And shall I also add the "Console app sample" and "AuthenticationManager sample class" in the same folder? Sorry for all the questions, but I'm fairly new to this :)